# Rails 5: disable access to Devise register and login form pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

I have **Devise** and **OmniAuth-Twitter** setup. I used to use email signup with Devise, then I switched to Twitter login. Now I need to disable email sign up and sign in access for everyone.

```
http://localhost:3000/register
http://localhost:3000/login
```

I tried the code below in views, but I get error. I assume because of it being an ActiveRecord feature.

```
redirect_to root_path
```

and I couldn't redirect in Controller as **before_action:** since I do not have controller for Devise.

**What is best way to disable access to this register and login pages?**

Thank you!

Comment: Just block from routes and make that link redirect to twitter sign in page

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to redirect from the login and registration pages, you should create two controllers that extend `Devise::SessionsController` and `Devise::RegistrationsController` and then configure your routes to use your controllers instead of the default controllers that Devise uses.

Here's an example for the login path only, but it's the same logic for registrations.

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions' }

# app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb
module Users
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    def new
      # Redirect wherever you want here
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Please note that devise allows you to skip some routes as well, but keep in mind that the whole *controller* will be excluded, which might not be what you want.

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, only: [:passwords]
# or
devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily that you need controller logic, it's that you need to block that ability from the view side. You have `appname/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb` and `appname/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` that you need to modify to remove the form fields that you want to hide and also delete stuff from your `appname/app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb` as well to disallow the signup there too.

You're going to want to delete the code that looks like lines 8-10 and lines 12-14 in your shared `_links.html.erb` file.

```
1 <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %> 
2   <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %> 
3     <div class="twitter-button"> 
4     <%= link_to "Sign in with #{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(provider)}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), class: "twitter-text" %> 
5     </div> 
6   <% end -%> 
7 <% end -%> 
8 <%- if controller_name != 'sessions' && false %> 
9   <%= link_to "Log in", new_session_path(resource_name), class: "forget" %> 
10 <% end -%> 
11 

12 <%- if devise_mapping.registerable? && controller_name != 'registrations' && false %> 
13   <%= link_to "Sign up", new_registration_path(resource_name), class: "forget" %> 
14 <% end -%>
```

But, at the end of the day I don't think it's necessarily a great idea to completely disallow people that don't have a twitter to utilize your app, because it greatly reduces the number of people that can now use your app right off the bat.

Comment: I don't think this would prevent people from logging in. Removing form fields also would not prevent people from logging in because the controller would still process the login.